# Views exposed form delta

Tags: views

My question is ,I have a views named for sale and it is exposed with some fields . I have created other 2 instances of this view using override this feature of views now I want to alter all three views seperately , for this i have used form alter but I am not getting the seperate ids for delta nor the #id for those .how can i alter those delta .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this goal via implementing [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

Let e.g.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'test' && $form_state['view']->current_display == 'page_1') {
       // do your alteration stuff
    }
    if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'test' && $form_state['view']->current_display == 'page_2') {
       // do your alteration stuff 
    }
}
```

Comment: @harsh If it works, Please approve this answer. so that it would disappear from unanswered list, and also useful for future readers.